# use grunt and angular-generator to manage multiple projects

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am currently using yo generator-angular scaffold to create base for building a couple of projects sitting on identical code base.

I want to know if there's any good pointers that can allow me to use the grunt tools to perform two different builds without been verbose like `grunttask:project1`, and more specifically with ngminPrepare how can you build more than one project at the same time?

the end result im looking for is as this

```
$grunt build:project1
$grunt build:project2
$grunt test:project1
$grunt serve:project1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do multiple builds simultaneously you can use grunt-concurrent: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-concurrent

You can just register a new task with the name you like:

```
concurrent: {
    build: {
        tasks: ['build:project1','build:project2']
    }
}

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');

grunt.registerTask('buildall', ['concurrent:build']);
```

Comment: thanks, and can you put in concurrent tasks inside the concurrent?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but I guess so. Remember though that the number of concurrent tasks that can run simultaneously is limited to the number of CPU cores you have.